# Database design with rectangular data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to learn SQL and database design and need some help with selecting a good design of my database in this case. I’m using C# and MySQL.
My input data in this lesson consist of energy meters, all with a unique identification number and every meter delivers one value per hour. I have data from 2013 and onward, and this will continue for a non-specified future. Best guess is 5 years ahead. There are roughly 25 000 meters so there will be 25e3 * 24 = 600 000 data points a day. I get this data once a day via file. The number of meters will change in a slow pace, so there will be around 500 changes per year, adding and removing meters. As a bonus I would like to know when the value was added to the database to calculate some performance-index of the collection system. So this is the input data for each meter:

- Valuetime (datetime)
- Value (decimal data)
- Date_added (datetime)

Every meter delivers one type of data so I can store a table with the type of data, so the data itself will consist of anonymous decimal values. This is where my problem begins. I have tried some different design approaches:

1. One large table with each row consisting of one-hour data, and one column per meter. Failure due to large amount of columns, and I need a separate equally big table with “Date_added”.
2. One table per meter, columns valuetime, value and date_added. Failure due to slow performance in C#-program.
3. Partitioned tables (i.e. table1 = meter begins with 1 and so forth). This still leads to many columns.
4. Partitioned table where table 10 = meter begins with 10 and so forth. This still lead to many columns.

All solutions above leads to quite slow performance when adding data to the database.

If I search Stack Overflow and elsewhere for database design with large number of columns I will always find the answer “Normalize!”, but I do not know how in my case because my novice experience. I have a unique value (valuetime) and I have unique meter ID, this is why I call my data rectangular.

Can someone please lead me to the right path?

Comment: Removed the `c#` tag. Tried to keep design-related and not Off-Topic and getting closed as Too Broad

Answer (score 0):

For your inputted data:

Meter Table:

```
ID int PK IDENTITY(1, 1)
MeterName varchar
```

ReadingsTable:

```
ID int PK IDENTITY(1, 1)
MeterID int FK
Value decimal
TimeStamp datetime
DateAdded date
```

You should populate this with an ETL - make an SSIS package or something.  Definitely better than a C# app, in my opinion.

Next, you can make aggregation tables:

DailyAggTable:

```
ID int PK IDENTITY(1, 1)
MeterID int FK
SumOfValue decimal
Date date
```

You can populate this after your ETL.  You can make weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly, etc. agg tables and schedule their population accordingly.  This will improve reporting performance.

Comment: It's mysql not sql server

Comment: Thank you for the answer! @Drew is correct, it is MySQL I'm using but your answer guides me anyway. One drawback is that I don't have acess to SSIS, so I will continuw with C#.  With this solution there will be a readings-table that has a quite large amount of rows, but that is ok?  And for the ID-field in each table, is there a drawback to use the metername as primary key?

Comment: If you guys need me for anything just holler

Comment: Numbers are better for primary keys since they're indexed faster than strings. You can create a unique key constraint on the name to ensure no duplicates. There are other upsides to using a numeric primary key but no need to cover them here

Answer (score 0):

Building on Stan Shaw's Answer...

If the data is a CSV file, simply use `LOAD DATA` each night.  You should probably load into a temp table, massage the data, then copy into the real table(s).  Possibly no need for any C# code.

`DateAdded` seems somewhat useless, and clutters the table.  Either remove completely, or build another table to record the uploads.

Don't bother with an ID on the main table; (MeterID, Timestamp) is the 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY`.  Again, this saves space.

I would build only *daily* summary rows in a single summary table.  That table might be fast enough to handle weekly/monthly queries.  Only if it is not fast enough, should you consider a summary of a summary.